# Django: send error to admin and return response to user

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I have got JSON API (as the part of the project) implemented with Django.
Sometimes I return error to user in JSON form. I want to notify admin via standard error reporting procedure via email (for example when uncaught exception raised). But I want to return some JSON response too, not 500 error page.
Some metacode to make sure that everything clear:

```
def request_handler(request):
    try:
        code_that_rises_an_exception()
        return response('{"result":"success"}')
    except Exception,e:
        notify_admin_about_error(e)           # <- this function is required
        return response('{"result":"error"}')
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've tried to google but can't find a solution. If I'm not catching exception – admin will be notified via email with stack trace and a lot of info, but same time user will receive 500 error instead of valid JSON response. I want to unite this two phases – send stack trace to admin and response to user.

Comment: you could also just modify the 500 error page to return JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) for this. Middlewares allow you to modify/process Django's HttpRequest object that is supplied to a view and HttpResponse object that is returned by a view as well as take action when a view raises an exception. You can do variety of tasks with this such as logging of the meta data of the requests you receive, error reporting etc. Django calls [process_exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) whenever an exception is raised by a view and you can define process_exception() to send a mail to you whenever an exception gets raised.

```
class ErrorReportingMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        send_mail_to_admin(exception) # you can collect some more information here
        return HttpResponse('{"result":"error"}') # this response is returned to the user
```

Add this class to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES variable in settings.py at the end of that tuple.

Your view would reduce to:

```
def request_handler(request):
    code_that_rises_an_exception()
    return response('{"result":"success"}')
```

Now if an exception is raised by request_handler, Django would call process_exception method of your ErrorReportingMiddleware which will send a mail to the admin about the exception and return a JSON response to the browser instead of a 500 page. I would implement send_mail_to_admin as an asynchronous function so that the processing of the response by django doesn't get blocked due to sending of mail and quick response is returned to the user.

Comment: Thank you for response. This way looks like very complicated. I made a very simple example in question, but real code would be very huge such way. I hope that there is a native method to send info. Though, if I won't find it, I'll use something like this.